# Do other numbered terms for spices besides hitoaji (一味) and shichimi (七味) exist?

Tags: words, food

I came across some words for spices, hitoaji and shichimi. It occurred to me that I have never seen the terms for 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 spices and so on. Do these terms exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Words of the form [number] + 味 do exist:

- 一味【ひとあじ】 *hitoaji* ≠ 一味【いちみ】 *ichimi*
- 三味 = 三味線【しゃみせん】 [*shamisen*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamisen)
- 五味【ごみ】 *gomi* "five flavours" (sweet, spicy, bitter, sour, salty)
- 六味【ろくみ】 *rokumi* "six flavours" (sweet, spicy, bitter, sour, salty, bland)
- 七味【しちみ】 *shichimi*
- 百味【ひゃくみ】 *hyakumi* "hundred flavours"

*Shichimi* is a particular blend of seven spices (chili pepper, sesame, tangerine peel, poppy seed, rapeseed, hemp seed, [*sanshō*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zanthoxylum_piperitum) — of course recipes may add other / leave out some ingredients).

As @Chocolate pointed out 一味唐辛子【いちみとうがらし】 *ichimi tōgarashi* (or *ichimi* for short) is sometimes used to refer to straight chili pepper (*tōgarashi*) without the other ingredients.

The others (3, 5, 6, 100) don't refer to a particular blend of spices.

Comment: `Except shichimi, they don't refer to a particular mixed spice` -- [七味]{しちみ}（= [七味唐辛子]{しちみとうがらし}）のほかに、[一味]{いちみ}（= [一味唐辛子]{いちみとうがらし}）ってあるやん？

Comment: @Chocolate Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Kōshinryō means spice too. Though I only know this from Spice and Wolf. :P

in addition there are several synonyms of spice which use the 味 kanji, and are translated as "condiment", "flavor", "flavoring" and so on, like kōmi 香味

@Blavius (who deleted his comment) is right, the only "number" attached to 味 that means "spice" or rather "seasoning" is 七味... all other number variants would simply translate to "number of" flavors...